# Changing <select> background colour after closing drop down box

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, highlight

I found some good solutions to change the colour of the items in the drop down box:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            select option:hover,
            select option:focus,
            select option:active {
                background-color: lightpink !important; /* for IE */
                color: #ffed00 !important;
            }

            select option:checked {
                background-color: green !important; /* for IE */
                color: #000000 !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option>Item 1</option>
            <option>Item 2</option>
            <option>Item 3</option>
            <option>Item 4</option>
        </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This works fine for the drop-down box (some strange colours, indeed):

[image]

After selection, the background of the highlighted item still remains blue as it is by default:

[image]

What can I do to change this colour too?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the rules of the selected `<option>` also to the `<select>` tag (e.g.: `select option:checked, select`).

Answer (score 0):

Below approach solves your issue, I've altered your CSS. Besides changing background for `option` I'm also changing background for `select`.

```
select,
select option:hover,
select option:focus,
select option:active {
  background-color: lightpink !important;
  /* for IE */
  color: #ffed00 !important;
}

select option:checked {
  background-color: green !important;
  /* for IE */
  color: #000000 !important;
}
```

```css
select,
select option:hover,
select option:focus,
select option:active {
  background-color: lightpink !important;
  /* for IE */
  color: #ffed00 !important;
}

select option:checked {
  background-color: green !important;
  /* for IE */
  color: #000000 !important;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Item 1</option>
  <option>Item 2</option>
  <option>Item 3</option>
  <option>Item 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have the impression that this is impossible. Different browsers have very different behaviour.

This is Firefox:

[image]

(not the colour I wanted for hover nor for selection)

In Edge, the drop down box is ok when opened, but afterwards, the background has its default blue colour:

[image]
(IE 11 has the same behaviour)

Chrome seems rather ok but ignores the hover colour:

[image]